# Vert.x - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No language implementation known for prefix D

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, vert.x

I am writing the [Eclipse plug-in for Vert.x](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.vertx). When `hello-vorld.js` is launched with a command line like:

`D:\Progs\vertx\vert.x-2.1M5\bin\vertx.bat run D:\Workspaces\runtime-EclipseApplication\Vertx2\hello-vorld.js`

I get the same error twice:

```
Failed in deploying verticle 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No language implementation known for prefix D
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doDeploy(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1614)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doDeployVerticle(DefaultPlatformManager.java:876)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.access$1500(DefaultPlatformManager.java:56)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$15.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:502)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$14.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:469)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Failed in deploying verticle 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No language implementation known for prefix D
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doDeploy(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1614)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doDeployVerticle(DefaultPlatformManager.java:876)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.access$1500(DefaultPlatformManager.java:56)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$15.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:502)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$14.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:469)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

`hello-vorld.js` contains

```
var vertx = require('vertx');

vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(function(req) {
  req.response.end("Hello World!");
}).listen(8080, 'localhost');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vert.x takes `D:` as a language runtime qualifier.

Use:

```
D:\Progs\vertx\vert.x-2.1M5\bin\vertx.bat run rhino:D:/Workspaces/runtime-EclipseApplication/Vertx2\hello-vorld.js
```

Comment: I wonder will jjs:path work to select Nashorn? Are there link for that?

Comment: If you associate the Nashorn lang to `jjs` (instead of `nashorn` as shown here https://github.com/vert-x/mod-lang-nashorn), yes it will work.